# Android quiz app tick mark issue

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a quiz app in android. for this, i am trying to implement a tick mark near the corresponding image in gridview when answer is correct which is retained even after the app is closed and reopened. how do i implement this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot of general stuff here. So you must do a little more research and ask more specific questions.

To get you started you should probably implement a custom View/Layout to show in your GridView, one that will have an ImageView which displays a 'Check' image when the question is correct.

For persisting this information you probably want to look into Sqlite for Android. This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) should get you started.